# ExtJS/CSS--button css styling not showing in IE8

Tags: css, extjs

I added some minor css styling to my button and it works fine in FireFox and Chrome but not IE

CSS

```
.search-button  {
    background:#00A300 !important;
    border-radius:20px !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}

.search-button .x-btn-inner {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    font-size: 13px !important;
}
```

BUTTON

```
xtype: "button",
itemId:"searchBtn",
text: "<b>Search &gt;&gt;</b>",
formBind: true,
cls:"search-button"
//baseCls:null
```

thanks

Edit: one thing I just noticed when I hover over the button or click it, its shows my background color around the border which then disappears on mouseout or depress of the button

Comment: try adding `background-image : none !important;` in `.search`

Comment: thanks for reply but no luck

Comment: Ok, so I must guess you're setting the class like `cls:'.search-button'` ... in this case you can add `baseCls: 'null',`... if you can show the settings of your button

Comment: baseCls: null had effect in FF and Chrome but again not IE. I ve also added my button config above

Comment: Also be specific with the version of ExtJS you're using

Comment: I am using 4.2.2 thanks